# HDMI video capture to miracast

Tags: hdmi, miracast

I would like to make the HDMI output of a server computer available in the LAN via miracast (or similar technology). Are there any devices which can do that? I have found a lot of miracast receivers (miracast to dongle with hdmi output) but not sender devices (hdmi to device to miracast).

I have access to the server via RDP as well, but it stops working sometimes and I consider this as a backup.